# JAXB Binding Exception

Tags: java, jaxb

I got the folowing error while parsing the XSD to Java Object

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Expected class ja
>   vax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType
>   but found class
>   javax.xml.bind.annotation. AccessType

Can any one give the solution for this error

Answer (score 8):

I would guess that you're running XJC under Java6, and have the `jaxb-api.jar` on your classpath. The classes from the Java6 runtime are clashing with the classes in `jaxb-api.jar`.

Remove the JAR from the classpath, that should fix it (if that's that's what the problem is).

Comment: Thank you so much Skaffman for you suggestion..It was really help me to fix the issue.....

Comment: @SivaGanesh: You're welcome. You can thank me with a vote and a tick.

Comment: I was also getting this error.  If I omit the api jar, I then get: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/AccessType

Answer (score 3):

if you are running XJC under java6, consider this page:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/xjc.html

Actually, xjc has been embedeed in jdk6 so you have to use 'xjc command' present in your JAVA_HOME/bin dir.