# AccessType issues using XJC Ant task for JAXB

Tags: ant, jaxb, xjc

While generating classes using XJC (using the Ant com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask task from Sun) I was getting the mentioned here:
[JAXB Binding Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310202/jaxb-binding-exception)

But now that I've omitted the jaxb-api jar, I get:
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/AccessType

Any advice how to fix the classpath for my XJC task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the given information looks like you are using jdk1.6 and you are not using the xjc.exe task under, java install dir/bin directory.

you might have configured the xjc task through other jars. please use the xjc/wsgen/wsimport tasks which comes with jdk1.6

Comment: i'm on OSX 10.6,.. but yeah, the xjc executable is inside my JDK also