# Java Ant - ERROR [main] - Could not instantiate auxFacto-ry named "DC"

Tags: java, ant, java-6, java-5

just a short one:

I have an application with an Ant-Build File which runs with Java 1.5.0_11.
I would like to run the application on Java 1.6.0_31.

But if I try to run my App vi a shell skript I get the follwing error:

```
    [importXML] 2013-02-21 13:25:16,165  INFO [main] - Creating cache manager from config file: /cache.ccf
[importXML] 2013-02-21 13:25:16,181  INFO [main] - thread_pool.default PoolConfiguration = useBoundary = [true] boundarySize = [2000] maximumPoolSize = [150] minimumPoolSize = [4] keepAliveTime = [300000] whenBlockedPolicy = [RUN] startUpSize = [4]
[importXML] 2013-02-21 13:25:16,185  INFO [main] - Setting default auxiliaries to DC
[importXML] 2013-02-21 13:25:16,190  INFO [main] - setting defaultCompositeCacheAttributes to [ useLateral = true, useRemote = true, useDisk = true, maxObjs = 10000, maxSpoolPerRun = -1, diskUsagePattern = 0 ]
[importXML] 2013-02-21 13:25:16,191  INFO [main] - No special ElementAttribute class defined for key [jcs.default.elementattributes], using default class.
[importXML] 2013-02-21 13:25:16,191  INFO [main] - setting defaultElementAttributes to [ IS_LATERAL = true, IS_SPOOL = true, IS_REMOTE = true, IS_ETERNAL = true, MaxLifeSeconds = -1, IdleTime = -1, CreateTime = 1361449516191, LastAccessTime = 1361449516191, getTimeToLiveSeconds() = -1, createTime = 1361449516191 ]
[importXML] 2013-02-21 13:25:16,192  WARN [main] - No such property [maxLifeSeconds] in org.apache.jcs.engine.CompositeCacheAttributes.
[importXML] 2013-02-21 13:25:16,192  INFO [main] - No special ElementAttribute class defined for key [jcs.region.main.elementattributes], using default class.
[importXML] 2013-02-21 13:25:16,215  INFO [main] - initialized LRUMemoryCache for main
[importXML] 2013-02-21 13:25:16,215  INFO [main] - Constructed cache with name [main] and cache attributes [ useLateral = true, useRemote = true, useDisk = true, maxObjs = 10000, maxSpoolPerRun = -1, diskUsagePattern = 0 ]
[importXML] 2013-02-21 13:25:16,216 ERROR [main] - Could not instantiate auxFactory named "DC".
```

Are there any knwon issues and differences betwen `Java 1.5 and 1.6` which could cause this error.

Regards
LStrike

PS: I am not allowed to post more specific details of the application, sorry for that.

[Edit]

```
 BUILD FAILED
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType.value()Ljavax/xml/bind/annotation/AccessType;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any kind of relative/absolute path use? importing anything?

Perhaps the file youre looking for isnt reachable, or it doesnt exist?

Was the factory changed to abstract or anything? Is it an interface?

With more details like these, we can help you more.

Also, how do i end a line here? i always have to hit 'enter' twice to get a new line.

Comment: I am not sure. I have not written the app. I am just porting ist from one linux machine to another. I have created all folder and filestructures as 1:1 copy of the old machine.

Comment: that relates https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=421   and that http://www.trackstudio.com/forum/failed-to-run-evaluation-instance-issue-293.html

Comment: if you can deal with this awful site view system maybe theres an answer there   http://osdir.com/ml/java.javalobby.communityplatform/2003-06/msg00081.html

Comment: I added the last line of the logfile in my post above, does this gives any hint to you?

Comment: I guess that youre trying to call, or trying to use(attribute?) something that doesnt exist. you should check what it is. i think the warn line can lead you further

Comment: do you have this line javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType.value()Ljavax/xml/bind/annotation/AccessType;   or some variation of it, or part of it?

Comment: whre can I find this cache.ccf file. If I search via locate I only get a very strange location for it:  /APPSVR/PRD/JBOSS/jboss-as-7.0.2.Final.inactive/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp576e22bd5e9dd25b/media_interface.war-7368bf209a8eae4/WEB-INF/classes/cache.ccf"

Comment: I think I found cache.ccf, but for this purpose I would have to change the code of the application. Hoping for a solution without recoding......

Comment: OK, I have to make a new build for Java6, won't work without. Thanks for your help. Problem is not cache.ccf, it is jaxb. The "old" jaxb is not compatible with Java6. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310202/jaxb-binding-exception.

Comment: glad i could help - which just shows anyone can help even without real knowledge of the given grounds, all that you need is some experience with compilation problems. again, glad i could help, good luck!